# Как сверстать с помощью flex конкретный блок

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сверстать подобный блок? С flex'ом не знаком, а городить что-то эпохальное не представляется разумным. Буду признателен, если поможете.

Сейчас сделано так (но это, соответственно, не верно):

```css
    .wrapper-center {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     flex-direction: column;
    }

    .container__item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #464646;
    }

    #bottom {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: black;
    }

    #big_block {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="player">
    <div class="wrapper-center">
     <div class="container__item"></div>
     <div class="container__item"></div>
     <div class="container__item"></div>
     <div class="container__item"></div>
     <div class="container__item"></div>
     <div class="container__item"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="big_block"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
  </div>
```

По сути, все вышло, кроме .

Comment: Просто по приколу решил написать: порадовал рисунок на листочке бумаги  XD

Comment: Спасибо )) Мне бы решение х)

Comment: а давайте вы в пеинте нормальный рисунок нарисуете, и вы точно изложите, что вы хотите... а мы тогда поможем))))

Comment: Хочу слева блок с 6 элементами одинакового размера и внизу один длинный. Все остальное место прямоугольника бы занимал один большой блок.

Comment: а почему менно flex? без него вариант не подойдет?

Comment: В целом подойдет, но что нужно применить к блоку, чтобы он встал на нужное место?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем все поняла в вопросе, но вот кое-что набросала с флексами. Надеюсь понятно. Стили нужно править.

P.S.: Суть `flex-box` в группировке блоков.

Просто для визуализации:

```css
.block {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
      .block-2 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 610px;
      }
      .flex-1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      .container {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
      }
      .block-3 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flex-1">
        <div class="flex-2">
          <div class="block"></div>
          <div class="block"></div>  
          <div class="block"></div>  
          <div class="block"></div>  
          <div class="block"></div>  
          <div class="block"></div>    
        </div>
        <div class="block-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-3"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: А, значит, у меня ```flex-wrap: wrap;``` был лишним...

Comment: А если мне нужно разделить <div class="block-2"></div> на 2. Я обернул его в отдельный блок, создал внутри 2. Но у них 0 ширина. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если ты хочешь, чтобы блок 2 был разделен на 2 части, то например так:  <div class="block-2">
          <div class="flex-01"></div>
          <div class="flex-02"></div>
        </div>
А для стилей нужно:
.flex-01, .flex-02 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 50%;
        height: 610px;
      }
      .flex-01 {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .flex-02 {
        background-color: blue;
      }
И добавить для блока 2:
.block-2 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 610px;
        display: flex;
      }

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2419757/54abed0b3ea1e1c810a077303b610f70

Answer (score 2):

Пробуем вот так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .main-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
.wrapper .main-content .left-side {
  width: 200px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper .main-content .left-side .list {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2px;
}
.wrapper .main-content .right-side {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
.wrapper .footer {
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="main-content">
  <div class="left-side">
   left-side
   <div class="list"></div>
   <div class="list"></div>
   <div class="list"></div>
   <div class="list"></div>
   <div class="list"></div>
   <div class="list"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">right side</div>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```